# How can I print "Hello Message" in Wordpress using a shortcode?

Tags: wordpress

I need to print "Hello Message". How can I print this message in WordPress using a shortcode?

Answer (score 1):

```
function HelloWorldShortcode() {
    return '<p>Hello World!</p>';
}
add_shortcode('helloworld', 'HelloWorldShortcode')
```

then you just have to type:

```
[helloworld]
```

anywhere to use it

Comment: No, But I don't no How to put this in shortcodes.php

Comment: Okay. Here check out this embedder for shortcodes

https://wordpress.org/plugins/embedder/

Comment: @AshuDesigner answered to you below, in comments to my answer

Comment: Thank You @Igor Yavych,@Trace Carrasco

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function my_amazing_shortcode_handler($args)
{
    $args=shortcode_atts(array('name' => 'dude'), $args);
    return 'Hello, '.$args['name'];
}

add_shortcode('hello_msg', 'my_amazing_shortcode_handler');
```

Use like:
`[hello_msg]` - produces `Hello, dude`
`[hello_msg name='Peter']` - produces `Hello, Peter`

Comment: where are you adding this? This is only possible if you add it outside of WP scope or at the point where file with this function is not included yet. I assume it's 1st one in your case. Add this to `functions.php` of your theme for example.